# how to add div dynamically

Tags: javascript, google-maps

i have searched a lot for this but i didn't got any specific realated to my problem, i want to add a div dynamically to my page but not inside another div but to the DOM actually means to say that the div should be add next to the div that i created for the marker  but not inside that one .
here is my code

```
<html>
<head>

<title>example</title>


<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>


<style type="text/css">

#map_canvas {
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
        background-color: #CCC;}

#menu_bar{
        width: 100%;
        height: 150px;
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0px;
        background-color:#008080;
        border-top:1px solid red;}

body{
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px;}




</style>
<!-- google maps Scripting start -->
<script type="text/javascript">

var markers = [];
 function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
        addMarker(event.latLng);
      });


    // add marker to positon
    function addMarker(location) {
         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: location,
                map: map
            });


    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(event) {
        infowindow.open(map,marker);

        //this.setMap(null);
        });


            $( "body" ).on( "click", "#addNote", function(){

            $('#addNote').parent().parent().append("<div>new div</div>");
            });

            // adding infobox to gMaps

            var popup= '<div> <img src="img/edit.png" id="addNote"/>Add Note  <img src="img/gtk_close.png" id="delete_marker"/>Delete Marker   </div>';
                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                         content: popup
                    });

         markers.push(marker);
        }

    // Sets the map on all markers in the array.
        function setAllMap(map) {
          for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            markers[i].setMap(map);

          }
        }

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
<!-- google maps Scripting ends -->





</head>

<body>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
<div id="menu_bar">




</div>



</body>
</html>
```

please help me thaks alot.

Comment: and you did find append and prepend from jquery?

Comment: yes sir i have tryed both of it but they actually append or prepend the divs to the same one.. means that the add the div inside the parent one i want it ouside next to it that it should popup separatly. @EricHerlitz

Comment: @Johnfranklien not clear where you want to add content can u pls clear..

Comment: No one can help you if you don't describe properly what you want. Show the HTML code of the structure where you want to add the next div, and show the exact place where it should be put.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a blank div element or any element and give some id to that. Now put this code on your javascript file

```
$("#givendivid").html('<div>Hello Testing</div>');
```

It will 100% work. but the best option is to hide the div and when u need display there.

Comment: .parent().html('<div>Hello Testing</div>'); use this it will work.